# Build a Column by applying a formula to an existing column (like in excel)

Tags: pandas, calculated-columns

I am new to the community. Hopefully this was not answered already.
I am trying to add a column to a DataFrame that contains a formula based on the previous columns. Example, build a series of stocks returns based on stocks close.
I know how to build a column by doing exactly the same thing to all elements of another, but not to use a columns element and formula to create another.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You'll have to show what you mean, at the moment this is all a bit vague, basically what you're asking can be done but we'd like to see input data, code and desired output

Comment: input : a dataframe with the close value of stocks, and output a dataframe with the daily returns of these stocks. I think I found the method .pct_change() that works well.